# How to verify google auth token received by android app on server side with perl

Tags: android, perl, google-authentication

I have an android app and a web server it communicates with. Application takes users account (email) and receives Access Token from google as described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Android part is working well, I got a token and sending it to my server. Here comes the question. How I can verify this token using perl? Google provides only examples for java, ruby and php...

Comment: Is it you who started writing a new CPAN module GoogleIDToken::Validator?

Comment: Yeah. If you need something to be done then do it yourself. :)
Module is ready I'm just trying to get through all this oldschool hardcore CPAN interfaces, formes, registrations etc...

Comment: Good luck then! I just noticed because my CPAN smoker sent a couple of fail reports for this module, but this was just because of a trivial issue (Pod coverage was tested, but not everything's documented in the module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any existing solutions so I decided to write my own module.
http://search.cpan.org/~dimanoid/GoogleIDToken-Validator/

Hope it will save someone some time...

Comment: Added a pull request to your repo with finn and my changes: https://github.com/Dimanoid/GoogleIDToken-Validator/pull/1